# How Can I Change The Print Format Of A Nested Dictionary That Is Sorted In Python

Tags: python

I Have A Nested Dictionary Like This :

```py
all_teams = OrderedDict({'Iran':{"wins:":wins_iran , ", loses:":loses_iran , ", draws:":draws_iran , ", goal difference":goal_difference_iran , ", points":points_iran},
'Spain':{"wins:":wins_spain , ", loses:":loses_spain , ", draws:":draws_spain , ", goal difference:":goal_difference_spain , ", points":points_spain}})
```

The Values Are Derived From The Calculations In The Codes.

I'd Needed To Sort Them Like This:

```py
sort_all_teams = list(sorted(all_of_teams.items(),key=lambda x: (x[1].get('points','wins'),x[0]),reverse = True))
```

After User Enter The Goals The Result It Will Be Like This:

```py
for key,value in sort_all_teams:
    print(key,value)
```

```
Spain {'wins:': 1, ', loses:': 0, ', draws:': 2, ', goal difference:': 1, ', points': 5}

Iran {'wins:': 0, ', loses:': 1, ', draws:': 2, ', goal difference': -1, ', points': 2}
```

But It Would Be Great If I Can Changed Like This:

(I mean "Spaces"---"Comma"---"'"---And ...)

```
Spain  wins:1 , loses:0 , draws:2 , goal difference:1 , points:5

Iran  wins:0 , loses:1 , draws:2 , goal difference:-1, points:2
```

Thank You In Advance!

Comment: Could you add a step and do the following: ```key.replace("'","")   ``` and same for ```value```.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Do you know the basics of string formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced the print statement in your original code

```
from collections import OrderedDict

wins_iran, loses_iran, draws_iran, goal_difference_iran, points_iran = [0, 1, 2, -1, 2]
wins_spain, loses_spain, draws_spain, goal_difference_spain, points_spain = [1, 0, 2, 1, 5]
all_teams = OrderedDict({'Iran':{"wins:":wins_iran , ", loses:":loses_iran , ", draws:":draws_iran , ", goal difference":goal_difference_iran , ", points":points_iran},
'Spain':{"wins:":wins_spain , ", loses:":loses_spain , ", draws:":draws_spain , ", goal difference:":goal_difference_spain , ", points":points_spain}})

sort_all_teams = list(sorted(all_teams.items(),key=lambda x: (x[1].get('points','wins'),x[0]),reverse = True))

for key,value in sort_all_teams:
    #print(key,value) replaced print statement with lines below
    s = ['{} {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in value.items()]
    print(key, *s)
```

**Output**

```
Spain wins: 1 , loses: 0 , draws: 2 , goal difference: 1 , points 5
Iran wins: 0 , loses: 1 , draws: 2 , goal difference -1 , points 2
```